# Many objects with different textures in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm new to OpenGL ES 2.0 with it's programmable pipeline and I'm porting application that renders many objects all with different textures. 
So this will require calling glDrawArrays for each object and changing textures between calls? Or there's another way to draw multiple objects with different textures with single glDrawArrays call?

I'm asking because I noticed that doing many calls to glDrawArrays is MUCH slower when tried to use them instead of glBegin/glEnd with 'desktop' OpenGL.

I'm rendering map tiles so ALL textures are different, they are dynamically loaded (can't spend much time processing them as if they were loaded once) and also quite large (up to 512x512).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a simple built-in way to apply multiple textures in a single batch `glDrawArrays` call. There are, however, ways to make it work. One of the most common strategies is known as a Texture Atlas. Basically, the idea is to combine many images together into one larger texture, with each sub-image occupying a known sub-rectangle of the texture. When you map those onto your primitives, you supply the coordinates of the sub-rectangle corresponding to the image you want to display.

A texture atlas will work in a large number of cases, but can be comparatively complex to set up. If you don't have to do a different texture for every single object, the first thing to try would be to simply batch together as many primitives that use the same texturing as possible.

If you were not using OpenGL ES, you might also look into using Texture Arrays, if your textures are all of the same size.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I don't think I can use atlas because my textures are quite large (256x256 - 512x512) and combining 4 textures into one will not make much difference (but will take some time to create larger texture). Is it possible to bind different textures to as much texture units as device has and then in shader select texture unit according to vertex attribute?

Comment: Yes, it would be fairly straightforward to do so by binding one texture to each slot and then either supplying texture coordinates for each slot and mixing them in the shader, or by having the texture coordinates follow some pattern that lets you map them to a specific slot (for example, if the texture coordinate is between 0.0 and 1.0 it applies to the texture in slot 0, if it's between 10.0 and 11.0 it applies to the texture in slot 1, and so on). I did not mention this since it limits the number of textures to a fairly small number. In your case though, it is likely the best option.

Comment: Thank you! I just need to learn GLSL.. Do I understand right that there can't be 'array of samplers' in GLSL and each texture will come as separate uniform, so I will need a bunch of IFs to select appropriate slot instead of just textures[i]?

Comment: you are correct, arrays of samplers are, regrettably, not supported in glsl, a chain of `if` statements is likely the best you'll be able to do.