# How to draw many small Bitmaps in opengl

Tags: java, android, performance, opengl-es, bitmap

I am new to opengl and i want to draw many bitmaps fast. I wrote myself a few classes to draw bitmaps. If i use the classes to draw a few big bitmaps its fast, but if i use it to draw many small bitmaps its slow. here is my code:

painter class:

```
 public void draw(int id, FloatBuffer vertexBuffer) {
     // bind the previously generated texture
     gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[id]);

     // Point to our buffers
     gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
     gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

     gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
     gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

     gl.glColor4f(1,1,1,1);

     // Set the face rotation
     gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

     // Point to our vertex buffer
     gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
     gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

     // Draw the vertices as triangle strip      
     gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

     //Disable the client state before leaving
     gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
     gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
 }
```

Then I call it like this:

```
 painter.draw(bmp, vert);
```

"bmp" is the int value and vert is a FloatBuffer.
The bitmaps change position in every frame, so i calculate the FloatBuffer in each frame for each bitmap.

Do you think there is a faster way to draw it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to put the vertices of all bitmaps that you need to render in a frame in one big vertex array and render that in one go. However, to avoid switching textures manually, you would have to either create a texture atlas with all your bitmaps or use [array textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture), if those are available to you (you need OpenGL 3 or EXT_texture_array).

Comment: thanks for your fast answer, i will try to make a big vertex array and render that in one go. i use OpenGL ES 2.0

Comment: I think in that case you will have to use a texture atlas. This might be interesting to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230009/many-objects-with-different-textures-in-opengl-es-2-0

Comment: thanks again, i will take a look at it to, it will take a while until i can test it